# Scope of variables in Python when using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, scope, anaconda

I am a newbie to Python (and to programming in general). I have been trying to learn it by trial and error and have run into an issue.

The code I am trying to implement is to get the longest substring which is in alphabetical order. That is,

- For an input of '**abcdeasdccjh**', output should be '**abcde**'
- For an input of '**abbcdabcd**', output should be '**abbcd**'

The code I have written is as below:

```
s = 'abbcdabcd'
sub = ''
temp = '' 

for index in range(len(s)):
    temp = s[index]
    for i in range(len(s[index:])):
        if index+i+1 < len(s):
            if s[index+i+1] < s[index+i]:
                break
            else:
                temp += s[index+i+1]

    if len(temp) >= len(sub):
        sub == temp

print('final ',sub)
```

This might not be the optimal logic to implement for this but it seems to be working. Issue is, the final print statement keeps printing the initial value of sub variable. How do I overcome this?

PS: For the above purpose, if there is a better algorithm I can use, please feel free to share that in comments. However, that is only a secondary thing for me now.

Comment: You are making a comparison in the last if-statement: `sub == temp` should be `sub = temp`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yep! I didnt notice that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying that

```
sub == temp
```

Remember that the "==" operator is for comparison, NOT for assignment. You are comparing sub and temp instead of assigning. Use

```
sub = temp
```